# Array null element HasValue construct

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, nullpointerexception

I have a simple code block that calls a WCF service API(GetActiveDevicesByDetailId) , which gives a single array as a response. since, I don't have the right class object defined on client side to receive the response, am using **var** datatype and getting an attribute/member of the response(CustomerID). The API returns a single entity array which we use for Client side processing. Since, the API returns only single element am getting the value as described below. Also, to handle null (Ideally it shouldn't return null), I'm checking and returning null if it does.

Does this statement **vm[0].CustomerId.HasValue**  return exception when null is returned ? I checked this code for simple nullable integer. But how does this statement work for Arrays ?

```
var vm = client.GetActiveDevicesByDetailId(DetailID); 
            if (vm[0].CustomerId.HasValue)
                return vm[0].CustomerId.Value;
            else
                return null;
```

Worked around by, using GetValueorDefault().

```
var vm = client.GetActiveDevicesByDetailId(DetailID); 
            if (vm[0] != null)
                return vm[0].CustomerId.GetValueOrDefault();                                    
            else
                return null;
```

What is SO opinion on this ?

Comment: You have to have *right class object defined* and using `var` does not change anything here.

Comment: No, that is the problem now. We don't have exact definition for the response of the API. The if check i have written will check whether "v[0].CustomerId" has value, whatif v[0] itself is null and it tries to access its CustomerId column, does var datatype inherently handle this case ? or we get a NPE ?

Comment: How does your project reference the service? If it's through "Add Service Reference" then the definition for the return object should be there.  Is this a 3rd-party web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
vm[0].CustomerId.HasValue
```

shouldn't return an exception *provided* that vm[0] is not null. You should be checking this before checking the CustomerId value.

There's plenty of resources to explain how array's work (e.g. [Arrays C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)) so I'm not going to explain that here.

Comment: I understand that there are lot of resources. My primary doubt would be what if "vm[0]" is null, and it wont have a CustomerId attribute even. In java, that would be NPE. Is that the same in C# ?

Comment: var in C#, infers the type i.e. it's still strongly typed. If it the compiler couldn't match the type then you wouldn't get intellisense on vm[0] (I am of course assuming you are!). It'll still have the CustomerId property available.

Comment: "**shouldn't** return an exception provided that vm[0] **is not null**" - so yes, if `vm[0]` is null, you will get a null reference exception.  If the array is empty, you'll get an array index out of bounds exception.  This is why @Damon suggested you should check whether `vm[0]` is null or not.

Comment: Yes Thanks , I worked around this by checking for not null and using GetValueOrDefault(). I hope the code will not break now for null values also ?

Comment: Read the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) - "Retrieves the value of the current Nullable<T> object, or the object's default value.".  Note that `HasValue` and `GetValueOrDefault` are methods on *nullable* types - you can use them on, say, an `int`.  And if your array is null, you'll still throw an exception.